# Set dropdown list selected based on MySQL value

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [an option already selected on page load in drop down list and also changeble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068830/an-option-already-selected-on-page-load-in-drop-down-list-and-also-changeble)

I have a dropdown list:

```
<select name="province">
                <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                <option value="British Columba">British Columba</option>
                <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
                <option value="Newfoundland">Newfoundland</option>
                <option value="N.W. Territories">N.W. Territories</option>
                <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
                <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
                <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                <option value="Yukon Territory">Yukon Territory</option>
                <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
</select>
```

The form submits the choice into a MySQL database. This is a profile page. When the user comes back to this profile page to change the selection, his choice (which is grabbed from MySQL) should be shown as selected. Any ideas how to achieve this?

ie. When loading up the profile page again, check against the database, grab the field, compare it to the list and then select that value as selected.

Comment: It seems you already have it figured out, what exactly is the problem and does the province list also come from a database?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068830/an-option-already-selected-on-page-load-in-drop-down-list-and-also-changeble

Comment: Where is the php and SQL you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You got the correct logic, just do it!

```
  <?php
        $province_array = array('Alberta', 'British Columba', ......, 'Quebec');

        echo '<select name="province">';
        //get the user's setting with user_id from DB. You should get this before this script.
        $sql = "SELECT user_province FROM the_table WHERE user_id=$user_id;";
        $query = mysql_query($sql, $the_connection) or die (mysql_error());
        if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          $user_province = $row['user_province']; 
           foreach($province_array as $value) {
         if ($value == $user_province) { //if the province==the user's setting, make it default 
           echo '<option value="'.$value.'" selected="selected">'.$value.'</option>';
         } else { //else, echo it as regular
           echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
         }
       }
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
```

1. Establish a connection to database.
2. Ensure you can get anything like a "user_id" to
   distinguish different user province from database.
3. Then there's the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

Initialize the variables before the form is displayed.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  // if we're getting info from the form
    $defaultProvince = $_POST['province'];    // set the province to the selected pulldown
} else {
    $defaultProvince = "";                   // otherwise default to an empty string
}

$provinces = ("Alberta",                     // set up the provinces array
              "British Columbia",
              "Manitoba",
              "New Brunswick",
              ....
              );
```

Then within the form display routine I would add:

```
echo '<select name="province">\n';
foreach ($provinces as $province) {         // run through our array of provinces
    echo '   <option value="$province"';
    if ($province === $defaultProvince) {   // if the default province matches this particular array province
                                            // then we'll select it
         echo ' selected="selected"'        // xhtml 1.0 Strict/1.1 compliant
    }
    echo '>$province</option>\n';
}
echo '</select>\n';
```